# Getting error "Cannot read property 'appendchild' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I am making this website for sharing your own recipe. I am making input fields above and this is the javascript. It returns the error:

> Getting error "Cannot read property 'appendchild' of undefined.

It says so about the line `newTable.appendChild(createRow);` I cannot seem to figure out what is wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Baksnakk.css">
        <title>Baksnakk.no - Hovedside</title>
    <style></style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="page-header">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4"><h1>Baksnakk.no <small>Slagord.jpg</small></h1></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li><a href="Baksnakk.html">Hjem</a></li>
                                <li><a href="Baksnakk - Kanelsnurrer.html">Kanelsnurrer</a></li>
                                <li><a href="Baksnakk - Custom.html">Lag din egen oppskrift!</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5"></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <div class="jumbotron">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Navn på oppskrift..." aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">og</span>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Antall personer...">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Legg til!</button>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                   <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrediens..." aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">og</span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Mengde...">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">og</span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enhet...">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Legg til!</button>
                            </span>
                        </div>

                   </div>

                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control largeInput" placeholder="Beskrivelse av fremgangsmåte...">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default largeInput" type="button">Legg til!</button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Beskrivelse av fremgangsmåte, stegvis...">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Legg til!</button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <button class="btn btn-success newRecipie">Neste oppskrift!</button>
                </div>
            </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        var headingButton = document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-default") [1];
        var tableButton = document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-default") [2]
        var newRecipieButton = document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-success newRecipie") [0];
        var containerFluid = document.getElementsByClassName("container-fluid") [0];

        var recipieCounter = 0;

        function headingFunction() {
            if (recipieCounter%2 == 0) {
                recipieName = document.getElementsByClassName("form-control") [1].value;
                nrPersons = document.getElementsByClassName("form-control") [2].value;

                createJumbotron = document.createElement("div");
                createJumbotron.className = "jumbotron";
                containerFluid.appendChild(createJumbotron);

                newJumbotron = document.getElementsByClassName("jumbotron") [1];
                createPanel = document.createElement("div");
                createPanel.className = "panel panel-default";
                newJumbotron.appendChild(createPanel);

                newPanel = document.getElementsByClassName("panel panel-default") [0];
                createPanelHeading = document.createElement("div");
                createPanelHeading.className = "panel-heading";
                newPanel.appendChild(createPanelHeading);

                newPanelHeading = document.getElementsByClassName("panel-heading") [0];
                createH2 = document.createElement("h2");
                createH2.className = "headingTwo";
                newPanelHeading.appendChild(createH2);

                headingTwo = document.getElementsByClassName("headingTwo") [recipieCounter];
                headingTwo.innerHTML = recipieName + " - " + nrPersons + " personer";

                createTable = document.createElement("TABLE");
                createTable.classname = "table";
                newPanel.appendChild(createTable);

                newTable = document.getElementsByClassName("table") [0];
                createRow = document.createElement("TR");
                createRow.className = "tableRow";
                newTable.appendChild(createRow);

                newRow = document.getElementsByClassName("tableRow") [0];
                createCell = document.createElement("TD");
                createCell.className = "tableCell";
                newRow.appendChild(createCell);

                newCell = document.getElementsByClassName("tableCell") [0];
                newCell.innerHTML = "Hei";

                console.log(recipieName);
                console.log(nrPersons);
            }else {

            }

        }
        headingButton.addEventListener("click", headingFunction);

        function tableFunction() {



        }
        tableButton.addEventListener("click", tableFunction);

        function newRecipie() {
            recipieCounter++;
        }
        newRecipieButton.addEventListener("click", newRecipie);

    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: How do we execute your code ? Where is `HTML` ?

Comment: What is your question? Is the error not clear? `newTable` being `undefined` means that `document.getElementsByClassName("table")[0]` returns `undefined`, which means that you don't have an element with **class name** `table`. Looking at where you tried to assign the class name reveals that you have a typo: `createTable.classname = "table";`.

Comment: @NikolaiScott That means you need to indent your code. A quick shortcut for that is to highlight all of your not-indented code and hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: I cant post the code in the post because its not indented by 4 or something. All the other code works exept the line that I have said...

Comment: Okay I made it. Thanks for the helpful downvotes in these dire times !

Answer (score 14):

This error is self-descriptive. It is telling you that `createTable` is undefined (has no value), and therefore you cannot access `appendChild()` on it. The line

```
newTable = document.getElementsByClassName("table")[0];
```

Is therefore not finding an element with class `table`.

This could happen if the DOM isn't loaded at the time of script execution. To avoid this, wrap all of your DOM-manipulating code in a `window.onload` block:

```
window.onload = function(){
    // your JS here
}
```

EDIT looking at your markup it seems that wasn't the problem, but I'll keep my answer here for posterity. Also, `getElementsByClassName` is not the preferred way of selecting elements. Typically if you want to uniquely identify an element you use an `id` and `getElementById`.

Comment: I am going to add some text from an array later on and I thought that using getElementByClassName was most useful because I could use for loops later on.

Comment: `gEBCN`is absolutely preferred for cases where it makes sense to select by class. Not everything needs to, or should, have an ID. That said, @NikolaiScott doesn't need to do DOM selection at all, since the element being fetched is already being held by a variable! It should just be `createTable.appendChild(createRow);`

Comment: Well, there was the solution! Thanks @squint! I still want to do it the way I did before though. Because that way I would have been able to push everything down using a variable...

Comment: You're welcome @NikolaiScott. Be sure to apply the same solution to other parts of your code where you're unnecessarily fetching from the DOM.

Comment: `window.onload = function() {}` was the issue for me, thanks for leaving it here :)

Comment: Thank you that you left your answer. ```window.onload``` solved my problem.