# What are the reasons why some Javascript code would work on a small static website but not in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

[Here](http://designscopestaging.com.au/test/test.html) is a test page with some .js code generated by the Bodymovin After Effects plugin.

However the same code generates the following error when I include it just before the `</body>` tag on a Wordpress site under development.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined
    at SVGRenderer.configAnimation (globe_2.js:formatted:4724)
    at AnimationItem.configAnimation (globe_2.js:formatted:6533)
    at AnimationItem.setParams (globe_2.js:formatted:6444)
    at Object.n [as loadAnimation] (globe_2.js:formatted:6281)
    at Object.loadAnimation (globe_2.js:formatted:1319)
    at globe_2.js:formatted:17169
```

EDIT: I get the same error if I include the code just after `wp_head();` in header.php.

When I debug the code, I can see that this is because the `wrapper` variable of the animation is undefined. And this is so because the `context` variable is undefined.

Looking at a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818361/getting-error-cannot-read-property-appendchild-of-undefined) in Stack Overflow indicates that this sort of thing might happen if the DOM wasn't fully loaded, so I attached to the `window.onLoad` event by wrapping everything inside the following code...

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(event) { MY CODE },false);
```

However the same error is still being generated.

I thought perhaps there was some sort of Javascript code conflict, so I turned off all plugins in Wordpress, no difference.

What other reasons could there be for the code to work on one website, but not another?

EDIT: Both sites are on the same server. Also, I duplicated the page source onto another HTML page and ripped all `<script>` tags out of it. No difference.

Any help is much appreciated, I'm starting to pull my hair out!

Comment: *What other reasons could there be for the code to work on one website, but not another?* How much time have you got?

Comment: Did you try moving the script source to just below wp_head to see if you get the same error

Comment: could you please clarify with sample of code of html and js becuase provided test page has nothing to clarify for us

Comment: @danwebb yep, thanks, just tried that then, getting the same error

Comment: Ok, human error is to blame. After deleting all other elements in the non-functional html I realised that I had included the word "lottie" in the class attribute rather than the id attribute. Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: Given that the code on both sites was not identical, should I delete the question? Or might someone else find this useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The js code looks pretty much self-contained. I do not think dependencies are at play. Focus your debugging on the following:

1. Do you have the wrapper tag `<div id="lottie"></div>` present in your html?
2. Does the js is included AFTER the wrapper tag?

Comment: This isn't an answer. It should be a comment.

Comment: I discovered that I had put "lottie" in the class attribute rather than the "id" attribute. Thanks Eriks!