# how to insert a svg tag inside a inner g tag

Tags: javascript, svg

What I am trying to do: insert an svg into a inner most g tag

Below is my code

```
    let svg = document.querySelector('svg');
    let g = svg.getElementsByClassName('srd-default-link');

    let shape = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
    shape.id = 'circle';
    shape.setAttribute('cx', 25);
    shape.setAttribute('cy', 25);
    shape.setAttribute('r', 20);
    shape.setAttribute('style', 'fill: green');

     g[0].appendChild(shape);
```

The result: only able to insert it in the first layer g tag and not the inner most g tag

Any advice is appreciated

Comment: Noted, sorry for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your source code there are two main problems:

1. You use the same `id` value many times. According to HTML documentation the `id` is used as unique identificator for an element.
2. You are "attaching" the circle to `<svg>` and not to `<g>` tag with the `svg.appendChild(shape);`

You can do something similar to:

```
var svgElem = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg"); //create <svg>
var g = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g"); //create <g>
g.classList.add("myClass");
svgElem.appendChild(g); //append <g> inside <svg>

var circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle"); //create <circle>
g.appendChild(circle); //append <circle> inside <g>

var g_2 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g"); //create another <g>
g_2.classList.add("myClass");
svgElem.appendChild(g_2); //append <g> inside <svg>


var coll = svgElem.getElementsByClassName("myClass"); //coll contains HTMLCollection

/* You cannot use coll.appendChild(circle);*/

coll[0].appendChild(circle); //append <circle> to the first <g> returned by getElementsByClassName("myClass");
```

Comment: since i have a exitising svg element, i call it this way let svg = document.querySelector('svg');

Comment: and I am trying to retrive the g tag inside the svg element, by calling it this way, let g = svg.getElementsByClassName('srd-default-link');

Comment: and append the shape to it, g.appendChild(shape);

Comment: but i got this error message instead: g.appendChild is not a function

Comment: any advice on this is really appreciated

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a HTMLCollections (array-like object). You can use `appendChild ` only in each element of the collection. So you have to use (for example) `g[0].appendChild` to append child to the first element of the collection

Comment: I have edited the answer fitting better your requirements

Comment: TypeError: g[0] is undefined

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818361/getting-error-cannot-read-property-appendchild-of-undefined

Comment: i put all the code inside the window.onload = function(){}, it does have error, but it not even went inside the function. weird

Comment: The image: [[Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/YxLt7nL.png?1)] shows i have 2 element inside htmlcollection, but g[0] returns undefined, i am at a loss

Comment: could you post all your source code editing the asked question? Thank you

Answer (score -1):

My own solution, I put a if condition,

```
if (g.length !== 0) g[0].appendChild(shape);
```

and I put it in componentDidUpdate at the first line. Thanks @Wolfetto for helping in the initial part. I will leave it here for anyone who needs it in the future.

```
if (g.length !== 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < g[0].childNodes.length; i++) {
            let item = g[0].childNodes[i];
            if (item.nodeName === 'g') item.appendChild(shape);
        }
    }
```